# Ionic 4 built in components vs home-made components

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I've been programming two apps so far in ionic 4.
My impression is that that built in components make it hard to "pixel-perfect" mocks and implement UX vision perfectly.
I know it is possible to code in ionic 4 without using built in components, for example: instead of using ion-header just a  with a class and appropriate business logic.
My question is: is it production-level appropriate to write custom made components? is it going to work in both android/ios, is it professional to not using ionic built in components. and if so, why there are no offical documentation on how to do it properly and responsively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it is professional, it mainly depends on your team requirements and how much time you may have to develop etc. One of the main goals the Ionic team had when making Ionic 4 was to become more framework agnostic in terms of the presentation layer. For instance, you can use Ionic's Stencil to create web components to be used with Ionic or within any other UI framework (React/Vue/Angular).

https://medium.com/ionic-and-the-mobile-web/let-the-framework-do-its-job-7788b0a967b2

Ionic will soon be supporting Vue and React as well, so with that in mind - I would say you have a free range of options when selecting your UI/UX components. I do think it would be a bit more ambitious to create some from scratch, and you'd save yourself a bit of time to use Ionic's components, but if having more flexibility around the design of your components than what is offered with Ionic's set of components is paramount, then I'd suggest building your own component suite.